# Copy array of strings to array of string pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

I am trying to copy an array of strings into an array of string pointers

but at the end of the range, I see that all elements in destination array are pointing to the last element in the source array.

I am new to go and want to correctly understand what happening under the hood.

Here is the code snippet to reproduce the issue

```
emails := []string{"a", "b"}
CCEmails := []*string{}
for _, cc := range emails {
    CCEmails = append(CCEmails,&cc)
}
fmt.Println(CCEmails)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/i6zJqoA4qAc

Comment: Put the code into the question rather than *only* linking to it.

Comment: Go `range` loops **reuse** the iteration variable, so to avoid the issue you're seeing you first need to create a copy of the iteration variable inside the loop, and use its pointer to add to the result array/slice.

Comment: @mkopriva Sounds like something worth posting as an answer.

Comment: whoever down voted, could you please explain the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what is happening under the hood you must understand the pointer and value semantics of `for range` construct in go.

It is clearly explained in this [ardan labs article](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/06/for-range-semantics.html)

```
    emails := []string{"a", "b"}
        CCEmails := []*string{}
        for _, cc := range emails {
                
                p := &cc
            fmt.Println(cc, p)
            CCEmails = append(CCEmails,&cc)
        }
```

The above code follows the value semantics. It copies the original slice and iterates the values inside the slice. While iterating it copies the values at particular index at the pointer. Atlast, the pointer points to the last element after completion of iteration.

To get the desired behavior, please use pointer semantics -

```
emails := []string{"a", "b"}
    CCEmails := []*string{}
    for i := range emails {
        CCEmails = append(CCEmails,&emails[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(CCEmails)
    
    for i := range CCEmails {
        fmt.Println(CCEmails[i], *CCEmails[i])
    }
```

The above code follows pointer semantics. It loops on original array and appends the address of particular element into the address slice.