# Is there a bug in handling slices with references in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a new list of structs that contains references to items that exist in another slice. It's easier to understand if you see it, so I've prepared a snippet that you can run.
I have a list (`dummylist`) of two points (Cartesian coordinates) that I want to parse to build a new list (`mylist`) with items having some features (in the example, X > 80). I've defined two points: {X:90.0, Y:50.0} and {X:20.0 , Y:30.0}. I expect that mylist will contain {X:90.0, Y:50.0}, instead at the end there is {X:20.0 , Y:30.0}. With some print here and there I can verify that the algorithm is working fine (it enters in the "if" condition in the right case), but, at the end, "mylist" contains the wrong element.

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

type point struct {
    X float64
    Y float64
}

type pointsList []point

type pointContainer struct {
    Point *point
}

type pointContainerList []pointContainer

// Prepare a slice with two elements
dummylist := new(pointsList)
*dummylist = append(*dummylist, point{X:90.0, Y:50.0})
*dummylist = append(*dummylist, point{X:20.0 , Y:30.0})

// My empty list
mylist := new(pointContainerList)

fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("---- At the beginning, mylist contains %d points", len(*mylist)))

// Filter the initial list to take only elements
for _, pt := range *dummylist {
    fmt.Println("\n---- Evaluating point ", pt)

    if pt.X > 80 {
        fmt.Println("Appending", pt)
        *mylist = append(*mylist, pointContainer{Point: &pt})
        fmt.Println("Inserted point:", (*mylist)[0].Point, "len = ", len(*mylist))
    }
}

// mylist should contain {X:90.0, Y:50.0}, instead...
fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("\n---- At the end, mylist contains %d points", len(*mylist)))
fmt.Println("Content of mylist:", (*mylist)[0].Point)
}
```

Here you can run the code:
https://play.golang.org/p/AvrC3JJBLdT

Some helpful consideration:
I've seen through multiple tests that, at the end, mylist contains the last parsed item in the loop. I think there is a problem with references. It's like if the inserted item in the list (in the first iteration) is dependent on the "pt" of other iterations. Instead, if I use indexes (`for i, pt := range *dummylist` and `(*dummylist)[i]`), everything works fine.

Before talking about bugs in Golang... am I missing something?

Comment: same *cause of the problem* as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910940/copy-array-of-strings-to-array-of-string-pointers (answer is in the comment)

Comment: in short `pt` is **reused** on each iteration, therefore the expression `&pt` evaluates *always* to the same value, i.e. the same pointer pointing to the same memory address, so each element in the container list is a *copy* of the pointer to the single `pt` value, which, at the end of the loop, will always contain the last element of the slice/array iterated over.

Comment: ... simply doing `pt := pt` at the top of the iteration block will fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're missing something. On this line:

```
*mylist = append(*mylist, pointContainer{Point: &pt})
```

you're putting the address of the loop variable `&pt` into your structure. As the loop continues, the value of `pt` changes. (Or to put it another way, `&pt` will be the same pointer for each iteration of the loop).

From the [go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements):

> ...
>
> The iteration values are assigned to the respective iteration
> variables as in an assignment statement.
>
> The iteration variables may be declared by the "range" clause using a
> form of short variable declaration (:=). In this case their types are
> set to the types of the respective iteration values and their scope is
> the block of the "for" statement; they are re-used in each iteration.
> If the iteration variables are declared outside the "for" statement,
> after execution their values will be those of the last iteration.

One solution would be to create a new value, but I'm not sure what you're gaining from so many pointers: `[]point` would probably be more effective (and less error-prone) than a pointer to a slice of structs of pointers to `point`s.

Comment: I know next to nothing about Go but did wonder why so many pointers; it feels too much like C, which I thought/hoped all these new languages were trying to help supplant ;-)

Comment: Unless you have good reasons because of considerations out of scope of the question, I wouldn't write this code using pointers since the aliasing problems can come back to bite you. Here's my version of your code: https://play.golang.org/p/9WlLoSmQmMK

Comment: Yes, they are scoped to the block of the for statement: I added a reference to the spec.

Comment: @PaulHankin no, your example is a little bit different. mylist should not be a list of points. A simple fix can be https://play.golang.org/p/3ZgoRJS65Z-

Comment: My example is demonstrating how I'd not use so many extra types and pointers to achieve the same results as your code. If you have a good reason to use so many types, container structs, pointers, pointers to slices and whatever, then you can disregard, but I felt the advice would be useful to you.

Comment: My example was just a simplification of a real and more complicated case. Your example is great to make that program working, but it doesn't deal with the point of the problem. Anyway I just wanted to make a clarification. In any case, thank you for your time